# SCP has some bug. The file copying using scp shows wrong progress

Tags: file, copy, scp

I usually deploy my release files to linux server using scp.

```
$ scp SomeData.tar.gz <serverip>:/opt/deploy/
```

Then it will shows file copying status.

```
SomeData.tar.gz                         100% 4403KB 163.1KB/s   00:27
```

But sometimes the progress of copying(100% on above example) is not correct, the progress value is 100%, but i checked the file size on the server, the copying was done only half.

After a minutes (The copying is finished), the scp command is exited.

I am really weird what was wrong with scp.

What was wrong with my configure?

Comment: I have the same problem, scp gets stuck at 99% and doesn't return, then I can see on the remote server that the file is only about half-way there and still slowly arriving. Probably some wicked "network write caching" going on that reports wrong information back to scp. But... what works in the software world nowadays? :D